# detemine which link has lead you in current page

Tags: javascript, php

Suppose we have a page (page1.php) with two links that they reference on same page (page2.php). I want to know which link leads the user on page2.php. because I want to control some access in page2.php. I have searched a lot and found some codes in ajax, scripts and forms. Is there any simpler solution?

Comment: This approach generally is insecure. You cannot rely on any information you get handed over from clients (browsers), since clients are under the control of users, not under your control. Since every aspect on the client side can very easily be faked any access control or other authorization strategy based on those aspects is insecure and vulnerable by design. So don't fall for such an apparently easy solution. If you need access control, then you should implement access control and not something that mimics access control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your page1.php you can add GET parameters to the link. Therefore, you add a `?param_name=value` after the path. Something like this:

```
<a href=page2.php?link=Link1>Page 2 </a>
<a href=page2.php?link=Link2>Page 2 </a>
```

When the users clicks on the link the values of the passed parameters are forwarded to the linked page. They are all stored in the `$_GET[]` array. By adding the parameter name as a key (like this `$_GET('param_name')` you can get the value.

So for your page2.php you can check the value of the `$_GET['link']` to determine which link has been clicked. This code should work:

```
<?php
    if ($_GET['link'] == 'Link1') {
        // do stuff for first link
    }
    if ($_GET['link'] == 'Link2') {
        // do stuff for second link
    }
?>
```

However, you need to be aware, that get parameters can easily be manipulated by the user. Therefore the URL is adapted. If you're looking for a secure way you should check out POST parameter and forms.

For more info on get parameters check out the php manual: http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

You could add URL parameters to the links and handling them on the page2.

```
<a href="page2.php?src=foo">First Link</a>
<a href="page2.php?src=bar">Second Link</a>
```

On the 2nd page you could handle them:

```
<?php 
if ($_GET["src"]=="foo") {
  // came from first link
}
if ($_GET["src"]=="bar") {
  // came from second link
}
?>
```